# Very complicated query, not sure if it possible. Involves not adding to a running sum

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a very complicated mySQL query I want to run, and I am having trouble thinking of how to write it.

Basically I have three tables:

```
a(aID, name);
b(bID, val);
ab(aID, bID, include)
```

What I want to do is create a query that creates a table like this:

```
c(aID, percentage);
```

I want percentage to be (total/possible) in this way. Total is calculated like this. Everytime an a row and b row have a relation AND include is 1 I want total to add the value of b.val. Possible will be the sum of b.val except where ab.include = 0

For example:

```
a:
+-----+
| aID |
+-----|
| 1   |
| 2   |
| 3   |
+-----+

b:
+-----+-----+
| bID | val |
+-----+-----+
| 1   |   1 |
| 2   |   1 |
| 3   |   1 |
+-----+-----+

ab:
+-----+-----+---------+
| aID | bID | include |
+-----+-----+---------+
| 1   |   1 |       1 |
| 1   |   3 |       0 |
| 2   |   1 |       1 |
| 3   |   1 |       1 |
| 3   |   2 |       1 |
| 3   |   3 |       1 |
+-----+-----+---------+

c:
+-----+------------+
| aID | percentage |
+-----+------------+
| 1   |         50 |
| 2   |      33.33 |
| 3   |        100 |
+-----+------------+
```

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT a.aID, (SUM(b.val)/(SELECT SUM(val) FROM b))*100 AS percentage
FROM a, ab, b
WHERE a.aID = ab.aID AND ab.bID = b.bID
GROUP BY a.aID
```

This gives the percentage aID is paired with bID with respect to weight, but I wanted to add this other calculation.

Is this possible?

Tried this but it didn't work:

I was about to try this:

```
SELECT a.aID, (SUM(b.val)/(SELECT SUM(val) FROM b,ab WHERE ab.include = 1))*100 AS percentage
FROM a, ab, b
WHERE a.aID = ab.aID AND ab.bID = b.bID AND ab.include = 1
GROUP BY a.aID
```

Comment: my desired output is seen in c

Comment: If you could give some context to your question (like telling us what "a" actually is) then it makes it easier to understand your problem (for me at least).

Comment: Ok so:

A is a person
B is an assignment that carries a certain weight (pass/fail)
An entry in AB with include at 1 means the person completed the assignment, no entry means they didnt, and an entry with AB with include set to 0 means they were not excused.

Comment: Why is `aID=2`'s percentage `33.33`?

Comment: 1    50% I THINK IT SHOULD B 66.33..WHATS THE LOGIC TO CALCULATE %

Comment: Because 2 had only 1 out of three possible b relations.

Comment: I googled "my sql running sum" and got several valid results, including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359077/mysql-running-total-with-count and this one that is marked as duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12077575/mysql-aggregate-by-month-with-running-total

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c611e7/13)):

```
SELECT ab.aID, SUM(b.val*ab.include)/(possible.possible-SUM((1-ab.include)*b.val))*100 AS percentage
FROM ab, b, (SELECT SUM(val) possible FROM b) possible
WHERE ab.bID = b.bID
GROUP BY ab.aID
```

numerator (total): Sum all b values where we have a relation

denominator (possible): From sum of all b values deduct values where there is a relation AND include is 0.

Comment: I will try and let you know!

Comment: YOUR OUTPUT DOESNT MATCH OPS EXPECTED RESULT THAT IS TABLE C

Comment: @AmitSingh Try using the CAPS LOCK key. There's no need to shout at everyone and it doesn't make people more inclined to agree with you

Comment: this did not give the expected result, but thank you for trying!

Comment: @Basic i m not shouting friend i m just little careless about capslock thats it..nothing else

Comment: Thank you for you help, this seems to give me the result I was expecting. I will try it in my code and let you know!

Comment: Thank you for the quickest answer I have ever gotten here, and for trying so hard to help me This solution worked!

How did you get so good at MySQL?

Comment: @AmitSingh: writing in all caps **is** considered shouting

Comment: @bam2403 Glad I could help! Just experience I guess :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ok i will b carefull from now on