# Limit On Accumulated Column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, limit

I'm trying to find an elegant way to write a query that only returns enough rows for a certain column to add up to at least n.

For example, let's say n is 50, and the table rows look like this:

```
id   count
1    12
2    13
3    5
4    18
5    14
6    21
7    13
```

Then the query should return:

```
id   count
1    12
2    13
3    5
4    18
5    14
```

Because the counts column adds up to n > 50. (62, to be exact)

It must return the results consecutively starting with the smallest id.

I've looked a bit into accumulators, like in this one: [MySQL select "accumulated" column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1135627/mysql-select-accumulated-column)

But AFAIK, there is no way to have the LIMIT clause in an SQL query limit on an SUM instead of a row count.

I *wish* I could say something like this, but alas, this is not valid SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM elements
LIMIT sum(count) > 50
```

Also, please keep in my the goal here is to insert the result of this query into another table atomically in an automated, performance efficient fashion, so please no suggestions to use a spreadsheet or anything that's not SQL compatible.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. One is by using `Correlated Subquery`

```
SELECT id,
       count
FROM   (SELECT *,
               (SELECT Isnull(Sum(count), 0)
                FROM   yourtable b
                WHERE  b.id < a.id) AS Run_tot
        FROM   yourtable  a) ou
WHERE  Run_tot < 50
```

Comment: I'm trying to get this to run. In mysql it's 'ifnull'. Also, what does count refer to, table a or b? What is ou?

Comment: I get the idea of what you're trying to do. Looks like it could work. One point against it is it runs in O(n^2).

Comment: Oh, that did work when I changed it to ifnull. Nice work! I'm gonna give you the answer. Thanks.

Comment: For anyone trying to do this in O(n) time, I'd recommend using the accumulated column approach I linked to in my initial question. This way is cool though too.